# How can I retain a value outside an if condition in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
            if (num_area>600 and frame_counter%10==0):
                print("Numberplate Detected and OCR is performing")
                cropped_image=image1[y1:y2,x1:x2]
                num1, data=paddle_ocr(cropped_image)#running paddle_ocr
                label=num1
                if not cropped_image is None:
                    filename = str(datetime.now())
                    fn = filename.replace(" ","")
                    fn = fn.replace(":","")
                    fn = fn.replace(".","")
                    fn = fn.replace("-","")                
                    img_name = os.path.join(output_directory+fn+".jpg")
                    cv2.imwrite(img_name, cropped_image)

            
                # Add label
            
                cv2.putText(image, label, (int(x11), int(y11) - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)
```

This is a part of my ANPR code, num1 stores the OCR detected value, I want that value to be displayed as my label. In this case, there is no error, but label is displayed only for 1/10 second. The whole thing lies inside a while loop

This is my requirement. Until num1 is detected, label can be empty, after num1 is detected I want that to be displayed as label throughout the video unless num1 value changes

I tried putting cv2.putText outside the loop, then I got error label is not defined. Then I tried copying num1 to another variable but still no luck.

Comment: There is no loop here (i.e. `for` or `while`). Did you mean to include a loop, or are you asking about if-statements rather than loops?

Comment: @slothrop Sorry my mistake.
I just want to retain the value outside if condition, I am getting num1 for only 1 frame in my video. Hence I am able to display num1 only for that split second, I want it to be retained always. Just want to add that, whole part lies inside a while loop of video capture.